# In SharePoint JSOM, how to get a column in the list by name?

Tags: client-object-model, csom

The following code will get the list of all the fields in the SharePoint List, however what I m interest in is if a particular field exists or not.

```
  function retrieveFieldsOfListView(listTitle,viewName){

     var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
     var web = context.get_web();
     var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
     var listFields = list.get_fields();
     context.load(listFields);
     context.executeQueryAsync(printFieldNames,onError);

     function printFieldNames() {
     var e = listFields.getEnumerator();
        //debugger; 
        while (e.moveNext()) {
           var field = e.get_current();
           console.log(field.get_title());
        }
     }

     function onError(sender,args)
     {
        console.log(args.get_message());
     }
  }
```

Please note, I don't have a list view with this field in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check field name in a while loop:

```
var fieldExist = false;
  while (e.moveNext()) {
       var field = e.get_current();
       if (field.get_title() == "myfieldname") {
         fieldExist = true;
    }
  }
  return fieldExist;
```

Comment: ah sorry, I agree with your answer. But what I was looking for is .get_field('FieldName') or .get_fieldByTitle('FieldName') kind of code in JSOM api.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are no such functions in JSOM api.
I know that it's trick, but you can try receive any item in a list. Then check field value:
...
context.Load(item); 
context.ExecuteQuery();
...
if(item.FieldValues.ContainsKey("myfieldname"))

Comment: Yeah using caml query, I was checking that. Thanks @BioGeneZ

Comment: Why can't you just make `executeQueryAsync` fail to tell you it does not exists? Something like this: https://gist.github.com/eirikb/1b1186ab2c7dd0370864